# Can we make similar sentences as to the meaning of the sentences using might

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, modal-verbs

**1.It was probable that he would go but he didn't go.**

**2.It was probable that he had gone./Probably he had gone.**

**3.It is probable that he has gone.**

Can we make similar sentences as to the meaning of the above sentences using might? What are the sentence that mean same as 1, 2 & 3. Please clear my confusion with proper explanation. I can't understand this type of sentences.

Answer (score 2):

1. He might have gone, but he didn't.
2. He might [well] have gone.
3. He may have gone. (Confusingly, this can also be expressed as 'he might have gone'!)

Comment: All the structures are same. This is where my confusion starts from. How do I know which meaning it refers to? How do I distinct between them?

Comment: As I said in answer to your earlier post, you can only tell the meaning from the _context_ of the sentence - what are the circumstances in which it was said, and what was said before.

Comment: Still I'm confused. Please clear my concept answering to this question. Might is the past form of may. Right? Then might can be used to express past possibility. Why have is needed with might to express past possibility? He might go. Luckily we reached his house and found him. Here 'he might go' can refer to the past possibility. Right? Why have is needed? Why might is used only for future or present possibility? Why can't Might be used to refer to a past possibility when it is in a single sentence?  I might go. Why can't this sentence refer to past possibility that probably I would go?

Comment: _He might go. Luckily we reached his house and found him._  If we found him, we know that he _didn't_ go, so there is no longer that possibility. We use the past perfect _he might have gone_ to show that the uncertainty existed further back in the past - before we arrived at the house.

Comment: OK got it. Now coming to the next point. I might go. This is a sentence. Now can I express by this sentence that 'it was probable that I would go' ? Because might is the past form of may.

Comment: I would say _possible_ rather than _probable_, but, yes, it could have that meaning.

Comment: OK. Then I can use might to express past possibility. Suppose there was possibility that I would go. Then I'll say, I might go. Right?

Comment: Yes, you could say that.